# c++ void* to parameter to a function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function-pointers, void-pointers

I have this function in some library:

```
class myConsole
{
    void addCommand( std::string command, void* fn );
    ...
}
```

and in my class I have this function:

```
void myApp::TestFn( const std::vector<std::string> & args )
{
    // do something
}
```

in the same class I call this:

```
void myApp::initApp( )
{
    myConsole::getSingleton( ).addCommand( "FirstTest", &myApp::TestFn );
}
```

but this gives me this error:

> error c2664 cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void(__thiscall
>   myApp::*)(const std::vector<_Ty>&)' to 'void *'

how can I solve this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you intend to use `void* fn` afterwards?

Comment: Does `myApp::TestFn` access any member variables of `myApp`?

Comment: I need to do something like this: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/ConsoleCode&structure=Cookbook

Comment: You should take a look at Functors, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses

Comment: Do you have control the declaration of myConsole, or is it a library by someone else? Either change it to accept a pointer to an object and a pointer to a member function, or a functor, or a pointer to a global function and a pointer to some arbitrary 'state' (which can just call a member function of the class pointer passed as the state). If not, you will have to (a) accept that it won't be portable if it assumes a function pointer and a void* are interchangeable (this works on many computers/OSes but not all) and (b) accept you need a global object which the command function will always use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[You can't](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.10) solve this. You can't reliably cast a function pointer to `void *` and back.

(I suggest you redesign the program and stay clear of `void*`; there's no real need for it in C++.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to pass a class method as it were a `void *` pointer. This cannot be done.

The right way of doing this is by using templates for the `void addCommand (std::string, void *)` method. Something like

```
class myConsole {
    template <typename T>
    void addCommand( std::string command, T f);
};

struct Callback {
    myApp &app;
    Callback (myApp &a) : app(a) {
    }
    void operator() (const std::vector<std::string> &args) {
        app.TestFn(args);
    }
};

void myApp::initApp( )
{
    myConsole::getSingleton( ).addCommand( "FirstTest", Callback(*this) );
}
```

This gives you the callback principle in C++, but I think you need something more flexible than this solution, since you actually want to choose automatically the command that will be executed by the callback (in this case `TestFn`).

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid `void*`, especially when trying to use function pointers. I'm going to assume that you are looking only at member-function pointers in the `myApp` class, and that you are only interested in member-function pointers which take `const std::vector<std::string> &args` as an argument. This typedef will create the appropriate type and call it `MemFunType`

```
typedef void (myApp :: * MemFunType) (const std::vector<std::string> &);
```

Here is a complete example (on [ideone](http://ideone.com/QZojZ)), where there are two different member-functions you may be interested in, `TestFn` and `TestFnBackwards`. This example probably isn't very useful, but it gives some examples of member-function pointers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct myApp;

struct myConsole
{
        typedef void (myApp :: * MemFunType) (const std::vector<std::string> &);
            void addCommand( std::string command, MemFunType fn );
};

struct myApp {
        void TestFn( const std::vector<std::string> & args ) {
                cout << " TestFn" << endl;
                for(std :: vector<std::string> :: const_iterator i = args.begin(); i!=args.end(); i++) {
                        cout << *i << endl;
                }
        }
        void TestFnBackwards( const std::vector<std::string> & args ) {
                cout << " TestFnBackwards" << endl;
                for(std :: vector<std::string> :: const_reverse_iterator i = args.rbegin(); i!=args.rend(); i++) {
                        cout << *i << endl;
                }
        }
        static myApp & getSingleton();
} ma;
myApp& myApp :: getSingleton() {
        return ma;
}

void myConsole :: addCommand( std::string , MemFunType fn ) {
        vector<string> words;
        words.push_back("hello");
        words.push_back("world");
        myApp &ma = myApp :: getSingleton();
        (ma.*fn)(words); // execute the member on the singleton object, using the words as the argument.
}

int main() {
        myConsole m;
        m.addCommand( "FirstTest", &myApp::TestFn );
        m.addCommand( "FirstTest", &myApp::TestFnBackwards );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but in this case I need to link in the console class the reference of the myApp class ( and if I have more than one class that call myConsole is hard...)

Comment: @ghiboz, I think you need to edit your question significantly. I would suggest that you stop writing code and try to clearly communicate what your goal is here. Is it true that you want `addCommand` to (in plain English) accept three pieces of information: (1) a reference/pointer to an *instance* of a `myApp`, (2) the name of a member function to be called on that myApp object, (3) the command string ?